# Longest prime $k$-tuplet such that each prime $p$, $\gcd(p-1, 420) > 2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, twin-primes, prime-gaps

What is the longest possible length $k$ of a prime $k$-tuplet (smallest groupings of $k$ primes) such that each prime $p$ in the $k$-tuplet,$\gcd(p-1, 420) > 2$. In other words, each prime $p$ in this $k$-tuplet is either $1$ $\pmod 3$, $1$ $\pmod 4$, $1$ $\pmod 5$, or $1$ $\pmod 7$. Also, given the longest possible following these properties, what is the smallest prime $p$ starting this chain? Thanks for help and explanation.

For prime twins primes $p$, $p+2$, such that ${p^2+2*p}

$p$ $=$ $1$ $\pmod {4*5*7}$, $p+2$ $=$ $1$ $\pmod 3$

$p$ $=$ $1$ $\pmod 4$, $p+2$ $=$ $1$ $\pmod {3*5*7}$

$p$ $=$ $1$ $\pmod 5$, $p+2$ $=$ $1$ $\pmod {3*4*7}$

$p$ $=$ $1$ $\pmod 7$, $p+2$ $=$ $1$ $\pmod {3*4*5}$

$p$ $=$ $1$ $\pmod {5*7}$, $p+2$ $=$ $1$ $\pmod {3*4}$

$p$ $=$ $1$ $\pmod {4*7}$, $p+2$ $=$ $1$ $\pmod {3*5}$

$p$ $=$ $1$ $\pmod {4*5}$, $p+2$ $=$ $1$ $\pmod {3*7}$

The smallest twin primes yielding these properties are:

$281, 283$

$1049, 1051$

$1931, 1933$

$659, 661$

$71, 73$

$29, 31$

$41, 43$

Would The longest possible length mentioned $k$-tuplet start on one of these forms?

Comment: I think you are asking the following question : at most how many primes $p$ are there such that $\gcd(p-1,420) > 2$? If this is correct, please get back, otherwise clarify.

Comment: How do you know there is a longest? Why can't the length be unbounded?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Yes, except I am looking for the smallest possible groupings of these primes.

Comment: I say, HOW DO YOU KNOW THERE IS A LONGEST?

Comment: LONGEST POSSIBLE LENGTH

Comment: @J.Linne, it might be possible that for every natural number $n$ there is an instance with length equal to that number. There is no reason to believe that a "LONGEST POSSIBLE" exists. It could be the case that you, or I just name the integer, and if you pick a sufficiently large prime, that'll form a chain of that length. whether its 2,10,$10^{100}$, or even bigger. That's what Gerry Myerson is getting at